# Unexpected results OpenGL projection matrices and pyglet written in python

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, pyglet

Before I apply a projection matrix to my model in modelview space it appears 3 dimensional. After I apply a projection matrix it becomes two dimensional, and if you can imagine the lines of a globe and how they wrap a sphere, my model has the lines flattened and inverted...when you can even see it. To see the model I need to scale it down a thousandth of its size. This would imply some sort of "magnification" problem in my projection matrix but I've nearly duplicated the OpenGL programming guide vmath::frustum(args) code word for word in a python port... The arrays are being passed to my shader in a column major form... I have regressed to fiddling randomly with parts of my functions in an attempt to change the behavior of the projection matrix, but... no matter which parts of the code I change it is either flat or appearing to be sucked into infinity.. it looks absolutely correct BEFORE I apply the projection matrix...which leads me to believe that there is some kind of automatic context creation deprecated cruft in the opengl pipeline specified by pyglet...I am writing the code as part of a learning experience for Opengl, and...I have no idea how some of the older specifications worked...Is it possible that there IS a projection matrix already being specified by pyglet automatically? Can anyone identify a common logic error that this sounds like? Do you need to inspect my code?

my shader code is

```
#version 430 core
in vec4 vertex_position;
uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = mvp_matrix*vertex_position;
}
```

*edit* this is my actual code...cut and paste...the last one was just me typing it into the browser from memory...and thank you for debugging it, but it does compile this way.
---that is vert_passthrough.vs
my fragment shader for thoroughness is similarly simple specifying frag color as blue.
July 14 addition -- matrix_projection_code

```
def projection_matrix(Znear = 1, Zfar = 100, Width = 400.0, Height = 300.0, camera_fov = 135):
    camera_aspect_ratio = Width/Height
    Top = (tan(radians(camera_fov*.05)))*Znear#Corrected via VMATH
    Bottom = -Top
    Right = Top*camera_aspect_ratio
    Left = -Right 
    if Right == Left or Top == Bottom or Znear == Zfar or Znear < 0.0 or Zfar < 0.0:
        return(Mat4x4())
    A = (2*Znear) / (Right - Left)
    B = (2*Znear) / (Top - Bottom)
    C = -(Zfar + Znear) / (Zfar - Znear)
    D = -(2*Zfar * Znear ) / (Zfar - Znear)
    E = (2 * (Right + Left)) / (Right - Left)
    F = (2 * (Top + Bottom)) / (Top - Bottom)
    G = -1.0
    X = 0.0
    proj_mat = Matrix(
            A,X,X,X,
            X,B,X,X,
            E,F,C,G,#Commented out to test...
#           X,X,C,G,
            X,X,D,X         
            )
    return(proj_mat)
```

And for full viewing pleasure some images.. before projection matrix applied and after...I am now wondering..well I'm not going to poison the well on this one.
*after projection matrix as lines this is the one that really has me thinking notice the elliptic portion of rendering...*

//before projection matrix as dots1
[before projection matrix as lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nquLb.jpg)

//before projection matrix as triangles3
//after projection matrix as dots4

[after projection matrix as lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vvtZ.jpg) 
//after projection matrix as triangles6
the stack wont let me post all of the images sorry.

Comment: This shader should not compile. The predefined variable is `gl_Position`, with upper case `P`.

Comment: It is impossible to debug this without seeing the actual code for your matrix calculations. "which leads me to believe that there is some kind of automatic context creation deprecated cruft in the opengl pipeline specified by pyglet.." No, there isn't. Your vertex shader does the object to clip space transformations, and nothing else will do that behind your back.

Comment: It looks like the problem might be with your port of the `vmath::frustum(args)`. Try printing out the projection matrix.

Comment: ---python 3.4.2 ---clipped..
>>> import matrices
>>> x = matrices.projection_matrix()
>>>print(x)
6.336718004866206-0.0-0.0-0.0
0.0-8.448967339821602-0.0-0.0
0.0-0.0-1.0202020202020202--1.0
0.0-0.0--2.020202020202020203-0.0